# проблема с выводом данных в простом mvc

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

есть таблица: `resums` (`id`, `year`, `site`, `desription`).
с которой нужно вывести все данные(3 строки, к примеру)

функция модели:

```
public function get_data(){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM resums;");
    return mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    //return mysql_result($result,0); 
}
```

контроллер:

```
function action_index() {

    $data = $this->model->get_data();       
    $this->view->generate('portfolio_view.php','template_view.php', $data);
}
```

и php'шная часть вьюхи:

```
 foreach($data as $row) {
    echo '<td> '.$row.' </td>';
 }
 var_dump($data);
```

сколько бы строк не было, выводит только 1ю. Если посмотреть на то, что отдаст var_dump(), то тоже будет только 1 строка. 
Как это можно исправить и подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array возвращает одну строку результата

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функиция `mysql_fetch_array` возвращает только *одну строку данных*. Нужно как-то так:

```
public function get_data(){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM resums;");
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Подробнее: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

**UPD:**

Расширение `mysql` давным-давно устарело. Настоятельно рекомендую вам перейти на `PDO` или хотя бы `mysqli`.